# Does Telepathy give the ability to detect thoughts?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, telepathy

The Monster Manual 1 states in the Pseudodragon entry (Pg. 210):

> Telepathy (Su): Pseudodragons can communicate telepathically with creatures that speak Common or Sylvan, provided they
>   are within 60 feet.

It later in the the passage states (Pg. 211):

> PSEUDODRAGON COMPANIONS 
> A pseudodragon may very rarely seek humanoid companionship.
>   It stalks a candidate silently for days, reading his or her thoughts
>   and judging his or her deeds.

No where in the entry does it say the pseudodragon has the ability to listen to thoughts. So does telepathy automatically give the ability to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Telepathy is probably two-way, so a pseudodragon can telepathically say something to a creature without telepathy, and that creature could respond in kind.

Even this much, however, is not clearly or explicitly stated by the rules, and I can see arguments to the contrary.

Anyway, if we buy two-way telepathy, it’s kind of like reading thoughts, maybe. But more likely, the author of the pseudodragon description simply made a mistake.

Either way, telepathy definitely does not give the ability to spy on thoughts; that kind of thing requires spell slots and saving throws, and in any event nothing in the telepathy description remotely suggests it. Since the pseudodragon description implies that this is what the pseudodragon does, there is a contradiction between that description and the pseudodragon’s stats—nothing gives it that ability. I don’t know if the error was the failure to give the pseudodragon such an ability, or if it was describing it as if it had such an ability, but either ruling has no bearing on telepathy in general—if pseudodragons have the ability, it is in addition to their telepathy, not because of it.